# Как определить Android Device Id

Tags: php, android

Как на сервере используя php можно определить **Android Device Id**?

Пролбовал [android-market-api-php](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api-php/wiki/HowToGetDeviceID), но она к сожалению не работает.

Попытки извлечь информацию из глобальной переменной `$_SERVER` ни к чему не привели(

Может у кого есть положительный опыт?

Comment: Мне кажется определить можно, только лишь передав его на сервер с самого устройства..

Comment: А чем вас не устраивают куки? Android Device Id тоже не постоянный, и может меняться в особых ситуациях

Comment: Я надеялся что Android Device Id постоянный (ну по крайней мере на меняется без спец ПО), а куки не подходят, если к пирмеру разные браузеры использовать...

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите отличать как-то устройства на бэкенде, то Вы можете получить IP-адрес устройства... и использовать его в качестве идентификатора устройства. Конечно есть свои недостатки, но лучше чем ничего)

Если вам нужен именно `ANDROID_ID`, то надо только передавать на сервер.

Comment: В том то и дело, устройство мобильное, ip зачастую динамический, на сервер передать что либо (тем более что его нужно на странице как то извлечь) нет возможности.